# RuntimeFrameworkVersion is not selecting the specified version

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to publish my app using a specific .net core version (2.1.15). I have the following .net core versions installed on my machine:

```
    dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.109
 Commit:    586f23c400

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17134
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.109\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.7
  Commit:  b1e29ae826

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.505 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.511 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.109 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I also have the following in my proj file:

```
      <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
        <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
        <RootNamespace>CT.MicroSitesCore.App</RootNamespace>
        <StartupObject></StartupObject>
        <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.15</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore" Version="9.6.646" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.9.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.5.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly.Caching.Memory" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But when I publish, the version for Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll is 2.1.7.18340. It's the same if I remove the RuntimeFrameworkVersion tag.

What am I missing?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

2.1.7.18340 is the file version in C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.15 or C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\2.1.15

[image]